# possible to replace window.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I'm wondering whether it's possible to change the hash in window.location.hash and replace it with 'this.id'. Or would I need to change the entire window.location?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, you can. I do something similar at one of my sites, although with `href` instead of `id`, but `id` works too. A quick example:

```
$('a[id]').click(function(e)
{
    // This will change the URL fragment. The change is reflected
    // on your browser's address bar as well
    window.location.hash = this.id;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @jldupont: I should think so.

Comment: @BoltClock care to provide a reference to support this?

Comment: I don't have any sources except my own personal experience using it, that's why I said I *think* so.

Comment: +1: Tested it on: Chrome V25, FF12, Opera 12, all on Linux: it works.

Comment: This actually does not do a replace, it adds an entry to the history.

Comment: It doesn't replace on chrome for me

Comment: PLEASE be aware that this adds a history state in IE, regardless of how Chrome handles it.

Comment: From https://caniuse.com/#search=location.hash
"Supported in effectively all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc)"