# Is it possible to change the hashtag in a url?

Tags: jquery

I want to know if there is a way to change a hashtag in a url using jQuery.
For example, in the following tag,

```
<div class="comments"><a href="http://www.example.com/post/#comment">Link</a></div>
```

I want to change #comment to #response using jQuery.

How can I handle this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [possible to replace window.location.hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377150/possible-to-replace-window-location-hash)

Comment: Be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. Do you just need to replace one URL? or do you need this to be flexible?

Comment: `$('.comments > a:first').attr('href', $('.comments > a:first').attr('href').replace('comment', 'response');`?

Comment: @Dom. Thanks for your comment. I will try to use your code.

Comment: @Jordan S. Sorry. The Url will be dynamically changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and jQuery's [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will do the trick:

```js
//Select the link
var link = $('a[href="http://www.example.com/post/#comment"]');
//Change the href attribute
link.attr('href', link.attr('href').replace('#comment', '#response'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/post/#comment">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much